# Ansible AWX : playbook run successfully for create directory in localhost but when go and check to that location that directory not available

Tags: ansible-awx

I new with ansible AWX I wanted to create directory on my localhost for that create playbook as given below when I run playbook it shows that successful massage and changed on localhost but when i go to that
location the Directory isn't available there.

**playbook:**

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
   - name: Create Directory
     file:
       path: ~/newDir1
       mode: "0755"
       state: directory
```

**output:**

```
TASK [Create Directory] ********************************************************
20:16:58
10
changed: [localhost]
PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
20:17:00
localhost : ok=2    changed=1    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

**location got through output:**

```
{
    "path": "/var/lib/awx/newDir1",
    "changed": true,
    "diff": {
        "before": {
            "path": "/var/lib/awx/newDir1",
            "state": "absent"
        },
        "after": {
            "path": "/var/lib/awx/newDir1",
            "state": "directory"
        }
    },
    "uid": 975,
    "gid": 975,
    "owner": "awx",
    "group": "awx",
    "mode": "0755",
    "state": "directory",
    "secontext": "system_u:object_r:tmp_t:s0",
    "size": 6,
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "path": "/var/lib/awx/newDir1",
            "mode": "0755",
            "state": "directory",
            "recurse": false,
            "force": false,
            "follow": true,
            "modification_time_format": "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S",
            "access_time_format": "%Y%m%d%H%M.%S",
            "_original_basename": null,
            "_diff_peek": null,
            "src": null,
            "modification_time": null,
            "access_time": null,
            "owner": null,
            "group": null,
            "seuser": null,
            "serole": null,
            "selevel": null,
            "setype": null,
            "attributes": null,
            "content": null,
            "backup": null,
            "remote_src": null,
            "regexp": null,
            "delimiter": null,
            "directory_mode": null,
            "unsafe_writes": null
        }
    },
    "_ansible_no_log": false
}
```

Comment: Can you format the playbook & update the question, it's more readable, more chances of getting help

Answer (score 0):

If you are using awx docker image then you need to check created directory inside that container.
Get inside container and search. :)

[image: Screenshot of terminal session showing docker ps | grep awx]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. [Please don't post screenshots of text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/354577). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your answer. If you select it and click the `{}` button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.